# Redirecionar página passando "response" do ajax para uma div

Tags: php, ajax

Sei que a pergunta é estranha e pode parecer sem sentido, mas preciso de uma resposta, mesmo que seja para o `impossível`.
Faço uma pesquisa em minha `index`e preciso passar o resultado na mesma para uma outra página posicionando em uma div.
Fiz algumas pesquisas e tentei algumas alternativas, mas sem sucesso e como disse, nem sei se isso é possível.

O que tenho já tenho é isso, o retorno de uma pesquisa, consulto o `response` e já visualizo o conteúdo desejado.

```
$(function() {      
    $("#frmBusca").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var data = $(form).serialize();             

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'pBuscaGenerica.php',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'html',

                success: function(response) {

                    window.location.replace("outra_pag.php");

                    // EXIBINDO O RETORNO DAS INFORMAÇÕES   
                     $("#msgRamais").html(response);
                    // RESETANDO A FUNÇÃO
                     _toggle();                 

                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                    $("#msgRamais").html('×ATENÇÃO! Ocorreu um erro ao tentar obter o ramal. Contate o suporte técnico.');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Preciso redirecionar para uma determinada `div`, não vou postar as tentativas pois foram improdutivas e não acrescentariam nada ao post.

Comment: Quer colocar o resultado (response) dentro de uma div de uma outra página? É isso?

Comment: Olá @Miguel, exatamente isso.

Comment: Ainda não consguiu? Vejo que já atualizou o código... Pelo que vejo quer então redirecionar para outra página quando recebe a response é isso?

Comment: Olá @Miguel, o que preciso é meio complexo, preciso passar o response para a próxima página e mostrar ela em um div, mas não sei se isso é possível.

Comment: Claro que é, siga os passos da minha resposta. Leia também as notas. Quer fazer um redirect para a outra pag no succeso da função ajax?

Comment: redirecionar e passar o conteúdo do 'response'.

Comment: Resposta editada. Acho que é isso... Leia com atenção

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que percebi é isso que quer (a maneira que eu faria):

JS:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'pBuscaGenerica.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html',

            success: function(response) {
                window.location.replace("outra_pag.php");
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                $("#msgRamais").html('×ATENÇÃO! Ocorreu um erro ao tentar obter o ramal. Contate o suporte técnico.');
            }
        });
```

No lado servidor, php, armazenava as informações que queria passar para a outra página, isto quando realiza a chamada de ajax:

**pBuscaGenerica.php**:

```
session_start();
...
$_SESSION['ajax_result'] = 'isto vai ser exibido dentro de uma div numa outra página que não a que fez a chamada';
...
```

**outra_pag.php**:

```
session_start();
...
if(!isset($_SESSION['ajax_result'])) {
    // fazer uma coisa qualquer caso não haja essa variável, não tenha armazenado a informação
}
else {
    echo '<div>' .$_SESSION['ajax_result']. '</div>';
}
```

Algumas notas:

1. O seu erro é que que está a fazer `$("#msgRamais").html(response);` mas isto é inutil, não precisa disto nesta pagina (porque vai ser redirecionada para outra, `window.location.replace("outra_pag.php");`)
2. Caso seja preciso ter a variavél `$_SESSION['ajax_result']` definida para visualizar a **outra_pag.php** dentro do `if(!isset($_SESSION['ajax_result'])) {...` coloque o redirecionamento... Neste caso escusa de ter o `else {...` que está em baixo... Certifique-se que tem este redirecionamento no topo da página antes de qualquer `print` (output).

Comment: Olá @MIguel, qual o valor dessa variável? $_SESSION['ajax_result']; Onde você está atribuindo valor a ela?

Comment: É o que quer que seja apresentado na div, o seu response @adventistapr . Define isso na pBuscaGenerica.php quando fizer a chamada ajax

Answer (score 2):

Não vou postar códigos, mas a ideia seria a seguinte:

Realizar a pesquisa via AJAX. Armazenar em uma variável e passar a outra página via POST do PHP.

Comment: #Shura16 já respondi o novo post rss e sei que chato de fazer kkkkk

Answer (score 2):

@adventistapr, Assim o exemplo abaixo sobre Ajax + PHP

**Arquivo (index.html):**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="ajax_form">
        <p>Texto:</p>
        <p><textarea name="texto" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Descreva um comentario" /></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="enviar"/></p>
    </form>
    <hr><p>Ajax:</p>
    <textarea id="log" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
        var dados = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "log.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function(testlog) {
                $('textarea#log').text(testlog);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</html>
```

**Arquivo (log.php):**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    echo $_POST['texto'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem @KingRider, preciso repassar o conteúdo do 'response' para a próxima página, da forma como ficou o seu exemplo eu tenho que efetuar um novo resgate?

Comment: Este é um exemplo de código, para fazer cadastro e sair a resposta dar sucesso sem sair na página de sucesso.