# Mudar o valor de var e carregar a pagina php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, calendar

onchange não funciona, apenas funcionoa na primeira selecção, depois não.
ideias ??

```
function getComboA(sel) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var id = sel.value;
        $('#frontend').bcp({
            'ID': id,
            'loadURL': 'bcp/db/carrega.php',
            'sendURL': 'bcp/db/send.php'
        });
    }) 
};
```

Comment: O  que você tem além da primeira seleção? O que você quer dizer com "DEPOIS"?

Comment: porque tenho um select dropdown com aeroportos, e se selecionar Porto carrega as disponibilidades de Porto, caso seja Lisboa as de Lisboa..
ou seja, selecione o seu aeroporto de partida -> dropdown com value em foreach php da bd mysql .. 
Eu só quero que ao mudar o select mude o var id para o valor correspondente.

Comment: Os dados são carregados e enviados em json..

Comment: Porque eu domino PHP mas Javascript nem por isso.. e deve faltar algo, algum pequeno código..

Comment: Você recriou o elemento no DOM?

Comment: Sim... esta com dom eu acho que sim

Comment: A cada vez que você recriar o elemento, tem que chamar a função novamente.... testa ai e me diz se deu certo ok?

Comment: Por que não utilizar Ajax? é muito pratico para trabalhar com php + ajax. Veja o meu codigo de exemplo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144032/redirecionar-p%C3%A1gina-passando-response-do-ajax-para-uma-div/144050#144050