# Recuperar resposta de um post usando guzzle

Tags: php, json, post, guzzle

Eu estou tentando pegar a response de um porst json com o guzzle em um php simples.

Essa é a função em um projeto laravel que faz o post para uma url. (Estou usando var_dump para mostrar o resultado no terminal).

```
public function getPhotos($properties)
{
    $codes = [];
    foreach($properties as $property)
    {
        $codes[$property['codigo']] = $property['cod_filial'];
    }
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://local.app/file2.php', ['json' => \GuzzleHttp\json_encode($codes)]);
    var_dump($response); exit;
}
```

Esse é o arquivo php mapeado para `http://local.app/file2.php`

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');;
$input = json_decode($input);
echo $input;
```

O Guzzle me response vazio. Alguem pode me ajudar? Obrigado

Comment: 2 linguagem diferente e não recebe valor no mesmo tempo, utilize `$.ajax` pode ajudar. Veja o exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144032/redirecionar-p%C3%A1gina-passando-response-do-ajax-para-uma-div/144050#144050

Comment: Mas não são linguagens diferentes. Os dois são php.

Comment: Entendo, mas esta utilizando PDO? não e porém 2 linguagem são diferente.

Comment: Consegui. Era só modificar o `$response` para : `$response->getBody()->getContents()`.

Comment: Bom Ivan! Pode fechar ou apagar ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui. Era só modificar o `$response` para : 
 `$response->getBody()->getContents()`.